# Is it possible to estimate unobserved indicators with a fitted latent variable model?

Tags: estimation, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I have a structural equation / latent variable model that I've fitted (with lavaan) to a particular dataset $D_1$. I also have a separate dataset $D_2$ in which only a subset of the indicator variables are observed.

Given the observed indicators for $D_2$, **can I use the fitted lavaan model to estimate the values of the latent variables and/or the unobserved indicators?** If not with lavaan, is there another SEM package that has this capability?

NOTE: I already tried using `predict(model, newdata = d2, type = "lv")`. Whether I omit the unobserved indicator variables from the `d2` data frame or supply them as columns of `NA`s, `predict`/`lavPredict` fails with an error.

**Update:** I made progress by modifying the parameter table of the fitted model (deleting parameters associated with the indicators that are not present in $D_2$ and fixing the remaining parameters to their estimated/fitted values), "refitting" the modified model to obtain a new lavaan object, and then using `predict` to estimate the latent variables over $D_2$. Finally, I can estimate the unobserved indicator variables by manually reconstructing the model equations and using them to compute the (missing) indicators from the latent variables. (See the example R code below.)

Still, I'm not exactly satisfied with this solution. It would be easy to make a mistake in specifying the reconstructed equations (and for this specification to get out of sync with the original model specification, should it change), and I'm also not sure it's the most statistically sound approach to deriving the estimate.

`` fit = lavaan(model, d1)
modelPrime = parTable(fit) %>%    # using dplyr
  mutate(free = 0, ustart = est) %>%
  filter(lhs != "Y1" &
         rhs != "Y1" &
         lhs != "Y2" &
         rhs != "Y2" # & ... etc ...
        )
fitPrime = lavaan(modelPrime, d2)
estLv = data.frame(predict(fitPrime, newdata = d2, type = "lv"))
fitPrimeCoefs = as.list(coef(fitPrime))
estY1 = fitPrimeCoefs$`Y1~1` + fitPrimeCoefs$b_L1_Y1*estLv$L1
estY2 = fitPrimeCoefs$`Y2~1` + fitPrimeCoefs$b_L2_Y2*estLv$L2 ``

Comment: Did you fit the first model with missing data (that's a guess, not sure it will make a difference). If the items are dichotomous (or polychotomous) and you have a single latent, you can use IRT to do this, with the ltm package.

Comment: Could you combine the two data files and fit a single model? (You could even constrain to the original values).

Comment: @JeremyMiles Neither dataset has missing data (in the traditional sense, of values occasionally left out). I want to test the ability of the model to estimate hard-to-collect indicators (which are not present in the held-out $D_2$ dataset) when given only easy-to-collect indicators (present in both datasets). I think this makes the second suggestion a non-starter, because that would invalidate the test by fitting the model on the held-out data.

Comment: I should mention that I actually do _have_ the "unobserved" values for the hard-to-collect indicators in the held-out $D_2$ dataset. I just don't want these values to influence the estimate.

Comment: I see. What about fitting the model in the first dataset, then fitting in dataset with both sets of data combined, but constraining all values to their original values. This was the held out dataset won't influence the model.